# Swift check what way table view is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there a function to check what way the table view is scrolled? up/down.

I have an uiView that I need to hide depending on what way is scrolled.

I also have my table view inside an container view.

Thanks

Comment: set a delegate for `UIScrollview` or if that is accurate enough you can check it in the `–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` every time when you need to present a new cell (obviously because of scrolling) – it depends on what you really need.

Comment: @holex Thanks it kinda works. But since scroll views has that bounce effect it fires both functions "didScrollUp" and "didScrollDown" back and forth a few times if I scroll all the way to the top or if I do a "pull to refresh" This results in my view toggeling between hidden/shown a few times. So maby I am off adding a swipe gesture to the scrollview/table view?

Comment: @KiwoTew, if you use delegates of `UIScrollView` you may need to check whether the current offset is outside of the content's size, so you can pretty much detect when the bouncing starts, and can prevent the currently unwanted method calls.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIScrollViewDelegate` and

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

method

Comment: Thanks it kinda works. But since scroll views has that bounce effect it fires both functions "didScrollUp" and "didScrollDown" back and forth a few times if I scroll all the way to the top or if I do a "pull to refresh" This results in my view toggeling between hidden/shown a few times. So maby I am off adding a swipe gesture to the scrollview/table view?

Comment: Try to ignore negative `contentOffset`s

Comment: @KiwoTew please accept the answer if I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewDelegate is inherited from UIScrollViewDelegate, so you can implement this method

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) // any offset changes
```